# Add "quotation" in SAS using Find and Replace

Tags: replace, sas, find

I have a lot of 6-digit numbers in a SAS program:

898300 898311 898312 898313 898314 898315 898316 898317 898321 898322 898323 898324 898331 898332 898333 898341 898342 898343
898400 898401 898402 898403 898500 898501 898502 898503 898600 898601 898602 898603 898604 898605 898606 898607 898608 898609
898610 898611 898612 898613 898614 898615 898616 898617 898700 898701 898702 898703 898704 898705 898706 898800 898801 898901

I would like to do a quick find and replace using Ctrl+H such that alle the 6-digit numbers are "quoted":

"898300" "898311" "898312" ...

etc.

I think doing a regular expression search is the way to go, but I am not able to identify the specific syntax. Anyone who knows what to do?

Thanks

Comment: Is this happening in a SAS dataset (`.sas7bdat`) or the program (`.sas`)?

Comment: In the program .sas

Answer (score 0):

Am sure this could be done in notepad (replace all multiple spaces with one, then replace a single space with `" "`) but seeing as you tagged SAS here is a SAS solution.

first, compile this macro:

```
/***
  Converts a space delimited string into one with custom quotes / delimiters

  @usage
    %put %get_quoted_str(in_str=blah   blah  blah
      ,dlm=%str(,)
      ,quote=%str(%')  );
    returns:  'blah','blah','blah'
  @@

***/
%macro get_quoted_str(IN_STR=,DLM=,QUOTE=);
  %local i item buffer;
  %let i=1;
  %do %while (%qscan(&IN_STR,&i,%str( )) ne %str() ) ;
    %let item=%scan(&IN_STR,&i,%str( ));
    %if %bquote(&QUOTE) ne %then %let item=&QUOTE%trim(&item)&QUOTE;
    %else %let item=%trim(&item);

    %if (&i = 1) %then %let buffer =&item;
    %else %let buffer =&buffer&DLM&item;

    %let i = %eval(&i+1);
  %end;

  &buffer

%mend;
```

then call as follows:

```
%put %get_quoted_str(IN_STR=898300 898311 898312 898313 898314 898315 898316 898317 898321 898322 898323 898324 
  898331 898332 898333 898341 898342 898343 898400 898401 898402 898403 898500 898501 898502 898503 898600 898601 
  898602 898603 898604 898605 898606 898607 898608 898609 898610 898611 898612 898613 898614 898615 898616 898617 
  898700 898701 898702 898703 898704 898705 898706 898800 898801 898901
  ,DLM=%str( ),QUOTE=%str(%")
  );
```

which gives:

```
"898300" "898311" "898312" "898313" "898314" "898315" "898316" "898317" "898321" "898322" "898323" "898324" "898331" "898332" 
"898333" "898341" "898342" "898343" "898400" "898401" "898402" "898403" "898500" "898501" "898502" "898503" "898600" "898601" 
"898602" "898603" "898604" "898605" "898606" "898607" "898608" "898609" "898610" "898611" "898612" "898613" "898614" "898615" 
"898616" "898617" "898700" "898701" "898702" "898703" "898704" "898705" "898706" "898800" "898801" "898901"
```

The above can then be copy pasted back into the program..

Comment: Thank you so much. I'll try iy out.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the result is shorter than `%SYSFUNC()` limits I normally just use `TRANWRD()` function call for this. Compress multiple blanks to one first using `COMPBL()`.

```
%let list=A B C   D ;
%let qlist="%sysfunc(tranwrd(%sysfunc(compbl(&list)),%str( )," "))" ;
```